# React CSS Stylesheet not applying to only my solution

Tags: reactjs

My stylesheet for my React project isn't applying correctly to only one of my components. It works for other components, it also works for ALL the components when my coworkers are running the project, this seems to be a problem for only me. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: The main issue is that the same path is working for all my coworkers because we are using the same repo. None of them have this issue (specifically the component is a popup, which works for them but when I'm running it in my Visual Studio it just puts the component on the page in place instead of using the css in the stylesheet to show it as a popup) –

Comment: It could be your browser caching the previous CSS did you do something like *empty cache and hard reload*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [SoroushOwji commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576507/react-css-stylesheet-not-applying-to-only-my-solution/69576901#comment122979565_69576507), the browser was caching the previous CSS. The solution was to empty the cache and do a hard reload.

Answer (score 0):

Look at **import** in that component, maybe the path of **css** is wrong write, is better if some code is showed, then we can exactly say wich problem is!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).